# App-provided action launcher not working in wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an Android Wear application developed and working in wearable devices (watches). The application has Spanish as default language.

The problem is that the command: `"Ok Google. Start MyApp"` is recognized by the speech input but does nothing. It should start `MyActivity` but does nothing.

Note that I've translated the command here since the application language is Spanish, actually I say: `Ok Google. Iniciar mi aplicación`.

Here is the manifest for the wear module:

```
...
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />    
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/my_app"
        android:taskAffinity="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Where `@string/my_app` is `My application` (actually in Spanish: `Mi aplicación`).

Both the smartphone (Nexus 5) and the watch (Samsung Gear Live) are in Spanish.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the language in the 'Google' app is also Spanish.

Google app -> Settings -> Speech settings -> Language